# unable to log execution of package BIDS 2012 (SSIS)

Tags: ssis, bids

I have installed SSIS for VS2012 (SQL Server 2012) and I am able to create basic packages that run, however I am unable to get any of the logging to work.  I have configured logging for text files and for the SQL Provider however, neither will log the execution of the package which is just a few SQL statements.  I have configured all of the events to log in the details and in the advanced selections.  The exec SQL tasks are in a Data Flow container, which I have also enabled logging.
When I look for the table msdb.dbo.sysssislog it is there but it is empty.  If I configure the  file writer, it will not create a file, which I specified to be in \windows\temp to avoid any permission problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy your packages to SSIS Catalog, you can have access to a better logging system that is offered by SSIS2012. You can Right-Click on your project under `Integration Services Catalog` and `Report` `All Executions`. This is highly recommended and makes your DBA's life much easier. you can learn more about how to set this up [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/15/deploying-to-the-ssis-catalog.aspx).

Comment: This worked for me.  One other small piece was to actually install Integration Services on the install of SQL Server.  I am now able to see the logs after the package executes.  Thanks.